# Remove Halo recessed fixture completely

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting, removal

Older house built in the late 60's.  Trying to remove existing Halo (new work?) recessed fixture completely to  retrofit and extend circuit to one more fixture.  I removed the 4 screws (well there were only 3) and the can comes down about 1/2" to a fairly hard stop that feels metallic in nature.  Any thoughts ?

[image: Existing Fixture]

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what to do next. You'll need to provide an answer or accept one if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

With the power off, try pushing the can up into the attic. The can should break free of the bracket and only be held in place by the cable. Some of these lights have support ties that attach to the joists. Once the can is free of the bracket, you should be able to look up there and see how the fixture is fastened in place. good luck and stay safe out there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Upon closer examination the section of the can that did not have the hex head screw instead had a nail driven in a good ways above the slot.  The head of the nail looked like a hole.  I cannot fathom how they swung the hammer to drive it in.  Go figure.

Comment: @jonnieD You should write this up as an answer to your own question.